# assertRaises fails, even the callable raises the required exception (python, unitest)

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following test-code checking for an exception raising in a function. I expect the test to pass, but a failure is indicated instead. Here is the test code:

```
import unittest

# define a user-defined exception
class MyException(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return repr("ERROR: Just raised my exception!")

# this is my main class with a method raising this exception
class MyMainObject(object):

    def func(self):
        raise MyException()

# the test class
class TestConfig(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1(self):

        other = MyMainObject()
        self.assertRaises(MyException, other.func())

# calling the test
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    unittest.main()
```

When `other.func()` is called in the assert statement, `MyException` is raised (can be checked easily). So, the `assertRaises` test should pass the test, as `other.func()` failes with `MyException`, BUT:

```
....
MyException: 'ERROR: Just raised my exception!'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I do not see something wrong, so I would appreciate some input on this problem.

Comment: You should notice it's an error, not a failure ! your exception was not even caught.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`assertRaises` calls the function for you. By calling it yourself, the exception is raised *before* `assertRaises` can test it.

Change your code to:

```
self.assertRaises(MyException, other.func)
```

and it'll work correctly. Alternatively, you can use `assertRaises` as a context manager (python 2.7 and up):

```
with self.assertRaises(MyException):
    other.func()
```

Using `assertRaises` as a context manager has the added advantage that you can now retrieve the exception instance and perform further tests on it:

```
with self.assertRaises(MyException) as raises_cm:
    other.func()

exception = raises_cm.exception
self.assertEqual(exception.args, ('foo', 'bar'))
```

Comment: I knew it was something rather simple. Maybe I should have looked at it another day... (2 minutes to wait until I can click the hook)

Comment: @Alex Don't feel too bad - I think this is more of a matter of unittest being unintuitive  - other testing frameworks work how you expected.

Comment: I am using python 3.3 interpreter in pycharm IDE. What if I want to pass arguments to the function under test and also include a message in case the desired error is not raised ? Example - `self.assertRaises(ValueError, person.set_age_method, -10, "Error: Person's age cannot be negative.")` With this, I get an exception: `set_age_method takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. How do I fix this ? Btw, the docs for this assertion don't clearly tell you how to do it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises . What is **kwds ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 you can only set a message when using the context manager option.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Thanks. I am a Java guy, learning py. Do you mean that I can set a message only by using this method: assertRaises(exception, msg=None) ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 exactly; so as `with self.assertRaises(ValueError, msg="..."):` then call `person.set_age_method(-10)` in the block.

Answer (score 8):

Due to the rules of the languages, the arguments are evaluated before the code of the called function is entered (and that's generally a good thing). Therefore, `assertRaises` can't catch exceptions occuring during evaluation of arguments. The workaround (in more than one API) is that you *pass a callable* to methods like `assertRaises`, so they can evaluate it in a place they can control and where they can catch exceptions. If the entire argument is a method call, the magic of bound methods allows you to state this quite elegantly, without `lambda` or such silliness:

```
self.assertRaises(MyException, other.func) # <- note, no parentheses after func
```

Comment: I am using python 3.3 interpreter in pycharm IDE. What if I want to pass arguments to the function under test and also include a message in case the desired error is not raised ? Example - `self.assertRaises(ValueError, person.set_age_method, -10, "Error: Person's age cannot be negative.")` With this, I get an exception: `set_age_method takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. How do I fix this ? Btw, the docs for this assertion don't clearly tell you how to do it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises . What is **kwds ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 Everything that goes after the function, including keyword arguments like `age=-10` (this is what the `**kwds` stands for), is passed to the callable. You should create the `ValueError` object directly, since its construction doesn't need to be delayed like the function call (exception objects are harmless if you don't `raise` them), so you want: `self.assertRaises(ValueError("Error: Person's age cannot be negative."), person.set_age_ethod, -10)`.