# Python Unittest - Unintended usage for assertRaises?

Tags: python

I wonder if there is a way to do the following:

```
class Test_Vector_test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        vector1 = Vector(2,2,2)
        scalar = 1
        self.assertRaises(NotImplementedError, vector1+scalar)
```

This test is failed with the following error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahandz/Documents/School/Programmeringsteknik och Matlab/dd1315pylab3-master/test/test_Vector.py", line 14, in test_add
    self.assertRaises(NotImplementedError, vector1+scalar)
  File "/Users/sahandz/Documents/School/Programmeringsteknik och Matlab/dd1315pylab3-master/lab/Vector.py", line 17, in __add__
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.007s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

even though you can see that it actually raises the error. How can I reach the desired functionality (checking if `vector1+scalar` raises NotImplementedError) **without** using the `vector1.__add__` method?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) to know how to use `assertRaises`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`assertRaises` awaits something callable that then will raise the error. `vector1+scalar` is evaluated **before** the function `assertRaises` is even executed. Either use a function, a lambda or `with`:

```
with self.assertRaises(SomeException):
    do_something()
```

See also [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

Comment: this worked for me, though I was seeing the same behavior as the op even when I passed a callable that raises `NotImplementedError` to `assertRaises`. I was testing in the context of a validation function that I'd written. Weird.

Comment: @JasonWolosonovich Are you sure that the error did not get thrown when constructing the arguments? `def r(): raise NotImplementedError; assertRaises(NotImplementedError, r)` works as expected for me.

Comment: actually, i figured out why from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516881/assertraises-fails-even-the-callable-raises-the-required-exception-python-uni

I was calling the function because I had to pass keywords in, which would require the `with` context manager in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `callable` type, not the actual code (which raises the error). The result would be this :

```
self.assertRaises(NotImplementedError, lambda:vector1+scalar)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `NotImplementedError` is raised while the argument is being evaluated, *before* `assertRaises` is actually called. Your code is equivalent to

```
x = vector1 + scalar
self.assertRaises(NotImplementedError, x)
```

You need to defer the (attempted) call to `Vector.__add__`.

```
self.assertRaises(NotImplementedError, vector1.__add__, scalar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your solutions guys. I think the lambda solution was definitely the easiest and most intuitive.

Before getting your answers, here's what I came up with myself:

```
    try: 
        vector1+scalar
        result = False
    except NotImplementedError:
        result = True
    self.assertTrue(result, msg="Vector+scalar did not cause the wanted error.")
```

The functionality is the same, but some additional lines are required.

Comment: Not a recommended solution.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation of [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

> Test that an exception is raised when callable is called with any positional or keyword arguments that are also passed to assertRaises().

`vector1+scalar` is not a callable, it is an expression.